# dyId: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pypy

I am trying to execute a python code using PyPy2 v5.10 on MacOS El Capitan 10.11.6. However, I keep getting this error during runtime.

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
>   Referenced from: /Users/macpro/Downloads/pypy2-v5.10.0-osx64/bin//libpypy-c.dylib
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>   dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
>   Referenced from: /Users/macpro/Downloads/pypy2-v5.10.0-osx64/bin//libpypy-c.dylib
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>   fish: './pypy contactTrace.py' terminated by signal SIGTRAP (Trace or breakpoint trap)

I have read from a few sources that its because El Capitan does not implement the clock but delcares it. Hence, one solution is to upgrade the software or comment out the declaration. Upgrading the software is not an option for me because I have a lot of other scripts running in that particular computer. I was trying to comment out the declaration but I am unable to find where I can comment it off. Also, will it really solve the issue? Or are there any more simpler solutions to it. I am not very familiar with the MacOS platform and am only using it for this project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a wrongly linked `libSystem.dylib`, and that will be hard to fix (e.g. checking libs with `otool` and modifying lib with `install_name_tool`). However, there are newer versions of PyPy. Do you have tried them?

Comment: I am using the latest version of pypy already. I don't see anything released after my download. Oh dear! How should I go about doing it then?

Comment: @confused_kid: Could you append the output of `otool -L  /Users/macpro/Downloads/pypy2-v5.10.0-osx64/bin//libpypy-c.dylib` to your post?

Comment: thank you for your offer to help! I simply did a uninstall and then a brew install pypy and the problem no longer appears!